# in a function can you retun a null to exit the function PHP

Tags: php

I am passing the two var's by ref to change them, and once I have changed them or one of the (8 loops) have found a positive in the string I am using, I want to exit the function, but I don't need to return anything because they are passed by ref.

I could just pass a copy of one and then ref the other one and set the var of the one that is copied = to the function and return that, but is there a cleaner way where I just call the function, the vars are set and I can move on?

```
function get_cat_size($urlstr, &$cat, &$size){ return null; };

$cat = get_cat_size($urlstr, &$size);
```

Does the first one work or not? Witch is better for readability?

Thanks for the input!

```
while( $i < $countz )
    {
    $pos = strpos($outdoor, $outdoor[$i]);
    if($pos != false)
    {
        $cat = $outdoorID;
            while( $j < $sizeArrayCount)
            {
            $poz = strpos($outdoor, $outdoor[$i]);
            if($poz != false)
            {
                $size = $outdoorID;
                return;
            }
            $j++;
            }
        return;
    }
    $i++;
    }
```

^ so this should work yes no maybe so?

So this is one of 8 loops set up in a order because they are least important to important, with different var = different stores.

Comment: in a loop you can add `break;` which exits the loop.

Comment: You can just `break` out of the loops and remove any `return` statements.

Comment: return null; or return; will work fine.

Comment: Here let me post the first loop maybe it will make more sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just return without a value:

```
function returnsNothing (&$a, &$b) {
    return;
}
```

Or simpler just omit the return statement at all

```
function returnsNothing (&$a, &$b) {
    // do something
}
```

Both snippets will make the function returning NULL.

Comment: @shapeshifter: And, so, therefore?

Comment: This is perfect so I can just return! Oh man reading the PHP manual just not helping ... making my head hurt lolz!

Comment: @Lightness Races in Orbit your a bit late to the party.  My comment was regarding the original post which stated return; returns 'nothing' or void.

Comment: @shapeshifter: Aha, okay. Arguably `NULL` _is_ nothing. At least it's largely indistinguishable, and quite by design at that.

Comment: Yes @shapeshifter is right. I really appreciated his comment. Thanks both :)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [`break`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.break.php) for returning out of your `for` loops.

I would personally avoid returning `null` within a function since `NULL` will be returned by default when there is no `return` value specified. You can read more here at [PHP: Returning values](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.returning-values.php)